# sharing data[array] between controllers

Tags: angularjs

I need to share data between controllers. My data is actually an array. I am able to share the data successfully but I have one more requirement. I need to clear this array from one of the controller. I have written a function sharedService.clear() in my sharedService. But that doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong here?can anyone please help.

```
services.service('sharedProperties', function () {
   var sharedService =  {};

    sharedService.personArray = [];

    sharedService.setPersonArray = function(newObj) {
       this.personArray.push(newObj);
    };
    sharedService.getPersonArray = function(){
        return this.personArray;
    };

    sharedService.clear = function(){
        this.personArray = [];
    };
    return sharedService;

});
```

Comment: Is `this.personArray1.push(newObj);` a typo? Should be `this.personArray.push(newObj);`

Comment: yes typo. Sorry I have updated it.

Comment: `service` is built around the `this` object, `factory` is buod around the return. I believe you are mixing these up.

Comment: Thanks  @Matthew.Lothian. Can you please tell me the right way of doing it.

Comment: @user911 ok i gave it a bit of an explanation bellow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you have explained you want a static service that shares person across controllers

```
services.service('sharedProperties', [function () {

    this.personArray = [];

    this.setPersonArray = function(newObj) {
       this.personArray.push(newObj);
    };
    this.getPersonArray = function(){
        return this.personArray;
    };

    this.clear = function(){
        this.personArray = [];
    };

}]);
```

Anything declared on the `this` object will be available when referencing the `sharedProperties` service. Declaring something with `var` will make it private to the `sharedProperties` scope and only be available from within the service.

in the first example `getPersonArray` will return a reference to `personArray` and i could change or edit the value of `sharedProperties` and by reference `personArray` anyway i want making the access methods pretty meaningless.

So you might instead do this to protect your `personArray`

```
services.service('sharedProperties', [function () {

    // private
    var personArray = [];

    this.setPersonArray = function(newObj) {
       personArray.push(newObj);
       return [].concat(personArray);
    };
    this.getPersonArray = function(){
        // will return a copy of the personArray at the time of request
        return [].concat(personArray);
    };    
    this.clear = function(){
        personArray = [];
        return [].concat(personArray);
    };

}]);
```

This way you can only edit the private `personArray` with your methods. But it does require you to call getPersonArray() to sync any changes between controllers.

I tend to use `factories` for instance objects or constructor function rather than static like objects.

Comment: why there is a return statement in setPersonArray and clear? I thought it would be only for getPersonArray.

Comment: because we are updating the internal `personArray` then returning a copy of it. If the value of `sharedProperties` is changed from the outside it will not affect the private `personArray`. So when you set or clear `sharedProperties` we return the updated `sharedProperties`

Comment: Thanks!! your answer is very detailed and have helped me a lot in clearing my concepts. I want to accept it but I still have this last issue. While accessing this shared service in my controller , I get error 'unresolved method or function getPersonArray()'.If I change it back to my old code, I can access getPersonArray(). What's wrong?           `myApp.controller('SubmitController' ,
['$scope' , 'sharedProperties', function($scope  , sharedProperties ){
 $scope.submitGridData = function( ) {
alert(sharedProperties.getPersonArray());
};
}]);`

Comment: Thanks!! I have accepted your answer because this one gives more information to a novice like me.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you've confused a factory with a service in the way you have defined it. Try the below code instead:

```
services.service('shareProperties', function() {
 this.personArray = [];

 this.clear = function() {
  this.personArray = [];
  }
});
```

Also, see [AngularJS: Service vs provider vs factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angular-js-service-vs-provider-vs-factory/17944367#17944367) for more details

Comment: do you mean I don't need the declaration var sharedService =  {};

Comment: If I remove this and try your code , while accessing sharedService like this sharedProperties.getPersonArray(); I get error 'unresolved method or function getPersonArray()'.

Comment: No, and you do not need to return an object either. Read the link that I posted for a deeper explanation about the differences between factory, service and provider

Comment: I didn't reimplement all your functions.
If you want access to the personArray, just use: shareProperties.personArray

Comment: Thanks!! I a new to Angular and messed up with services and factory. Thank you so much for clearing the concept.